# Propositional calculus

Tags: logic

Why ( P ^ Q ) === ( ~P -> Q ) ?

How to prove?

Thanks!

Comment: WHat on earth does the question have to do with AI?

Comment: Write out the truth table and it will be obvious

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not: `~P -> Q === P v Q`, it is not equivalent to `P ^ Q`

One way to prove it is to use a truth table:

```
P | Q | P v Q | ~P | ~P -> Q
0   0     0     1       0        
0   1     1     1       1
1   0     1     0       1
1   1     1     1       1
          ^             ^
          +-------------+
       these are equivalent
```

Comment: Thanks!
I checked and I really mistyped the question!

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the [truth tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) for each expression:

```
p | q | p v q
--+---+------
T | T | T
T | F | T
F | T | T
F | F | F

p | q | ~p -> q
--+---+--------
T | T | T
T | F | T
F | T | T
F | F | F
```